# exporting to table not aligned

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table from this link:
https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/table/offensive/sort/avgPoints/dir/desc
when **scraping** the table, the names and stats categories align but the numbers themselves don't.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get("https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/table/offensive/sort/avgPoints/dir/desc", timeout=30).text,
    'lxml')


def scrape_data(url):
    # the categories of stats (first row)
    ct = soup.find_all('tr', class_="Table__TR Table__even")

    # player's stats table (the names and numbers)
    st = soup.find_all('tr', class_="Table__TR Table__TR--sm Table__even")
    header = [th.text.rstrip() for th in ct[1].find_all('th')]

    with open('s espn.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(header)
        for row in st[1:]:
            data = [th.text.rstrip() for th in row.find_all('td')]
            writer.writerow(data)



scrape_data(soup)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ApDz.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because those are under 2 separate table tags. A table for the names, then the table for stats. You'll need to merge them.

Use pandas. A lot easier to parse tables (it actually uses beautifulsoup under the hood). `pd.read_html()` will return a list of dataframes. I just merged them together. Then you can also manipulate the tables any way you need.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/table/offensive/sort/avgPoints/dir/desc'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

df = dfs[0].join(dfs[1])
df[['Name','Team']] = df['Name'].str.extract('^(.*?)([A-Z]+)$', expand=True)

df.to_csv('s espn.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.head(10).to_string())
   RK                   Name Team POS  GP   MIN   PTS   FGM   FGA   FG%  3PM   3PA   3P%  FTM   FTA   FT%   REB   AST  STL  BLK   TO  DD2  TD3    PER
0   1             Trae Young  ATL  PG   2  36.5  38.5  13.5  23.0  58.7  5.5  10.0  55.0  6.0   8.0  75.0   7.0   9.0  1.5  0.0  5.5    0    0  40.95
1   2           Kyrie Irving  BKN  PG   3  34.7  37.7  12.0  26.3  45.6  4.7  11.3  41.2  9.0   9.7  93.1   5.7   6.3  1.7  0.7  2.0    0    0  37.84
2   3     Karl-Anthony Towns  MIN   C   3  33.7  32.0  10.7  20.3  52.5  5.0   9.7  51.7  5.7   9.0  63.0  13.3   5.0  3.0  2.0  2.3    3    0  40.60
3   4         Damian Lillard  POR  PG   3  36.7  31.7  10.7  20.3  52.5  2.3   8.0  29.2  8.0   9.0  88.9   4.0   6.0  1.7  0.3  2.7    0    0  32.86
4   5  Giannis Antetokounmpo  MIL  PF   2  32.5  29.5  11.5  19.0  60.5  1.0   5.0  20.0  5.5  10.0  55.0  15.0  10.0  2.0  1.5  5.5    2    1  34.55
5   6            Luka Doncic  DAL  SF   3  36.3  29.3  10.0  20.0  50.0  3.0   9.7  31.0  6.3   8.0  79.2  10.3   7.3  2.3  0.0  4.3    2    1  29.45
6   7          Pascal Siakam  TOR  PF   3  34.0  28.7   9.7  21.0  46.0  2.7   5.7  47.1  6.7   7.0  95.2  10.7   3.7  0.3  0.3  4.3    1    0  24.56
7   8          Brandon Ingra  mNO  SF   3  35.0  27.3  10.7  20.3  52.5  3.3   6.3  52.6  2.7   3.3  80.0   9.3   4.3  0.3  1.7  2.7    1    0  25.72
8   9     Kristaps Porzingis  DAL  PF   3  31.0  26.3   8.7  18.7  46.4  3.0   7.3  40.9  6.0   8.3  72.0   5.7   3.3  0.3  2.7  2.3    0    0  27.15
9  10      Russell Westbrook  HOU  PG   2  33.0  26.0   8.0  17.0  47.1  2.0   5.0  40.0  8.0  10.5  76.2  13.0  10.0  1.5  0.5  3.5    2    1  30.96
...
```

Explained line by line:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
```

This will return a list of dataframes. Essentially it parses every `<table>` tag within the html. When you do this with the given URL, you will see it returns 2 dataframes:

[image]

The dataframe in index position 0, has the ranking and player name. If I look at that, I notice the text is the player name followed by the team abbreviation (the last 3 characters in the string).

[image]

So, `dfs[0]['Team'] = dfs[0]['Name'].str[-3:]` is going to create a column called 'Team', where it takes the `Name` column strings and takes the last 3 characters. `dfs[0]['Name'] = dfs[0]['Name'].str[:-3]` will store the string from the `Name` column up until the last 3 charachters. Essentially splitting the `Name` column into 2 columns.

[image]

```
df = dfs[0].merge(dfs[1], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

The last part then takes those 2 dataframes in index position 0 and 1 (stored in the dfs list) and merges them together and merges on the index values.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I would love it if you could explain what happening on every line just so me and everyone who encounters it can fully understand it.